# How Can I Generate API Controllers in IntelliJ Rider?

Tags: c#, .net, intellij-idea, rider

In Visual Studio, I can generate API controllers in a Web API project by selecting Add | Controller:

[image]

From this menu, I can choose model class, context class and controller name and with a button press I can generate hundreds of lines of boilerplate.

I've moved to IntelliJ Rider, but I can't find a way to generate controllers. Does anyone know if this can be done with point and click? If not, are there terminal commands to do this?

Comment: For others who might be interested in the answer: As of September 11, 2017, this feature does not exist in IntelliJ Rider.

Comment: As of 2020-10-18, I don't see this template. Had to add copy from VS templates. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Creating_a_File_Template.html

Answer (score 2):

This is possible as of v2021.1

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2021/03/18/scaffolding-for-asp-net-core-projects-comes-to-rider-2021-1/